# Is there a performance cost to passing all props to a react component with spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

Currently I find myself writing alot of components like the following:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      someState1: 'something',
      someState2: 'something',
      someState3: 'something'
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentOne prop1={this.someState1} {...this.props}/>
      <ComponentTwo prop2={this.someState2} {...this.props}/>
      <ComponentThree prop3={this.someState3} {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Higher level state is passed down through the props as normal and spread into the child component.

In some instances I find I am spreading all the props into every child component, as it is quicker/easier than specifying props.

So the questions are:

1. Is there a performance cost to spreading all props into every components, even if there could 10s of children components?
2. Should I be more specific with what props are passed to every component?
3. Are there any downsides to doing this for every child component?

Comment: Here is a pretty interesting discussion about the performance when connecting "too many" components: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/419

Comment: its not much a performance cost but more a clearness cost

Comment: why not use redux in your case? it's made exactly for this purpose, so you can stop passing a lot of props to different components

Comment: definitely use redux or literally any other method of state management, this will get out of hand very quickly

Comment: Perhaps it is time to move to a state management library in my current application but I'm hesitant to use one as a silver bullet in all my projects.